# Are all the people on planet Zeist immortal/Immortal?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise, highlander-2

From *Highlander 2* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_II:_The_Quickening):

> On the planet Zeist, a last meeting is held between the members of a rebellion against the rule of General Katana. The rebellion’s leader, Ramirez, chooses "a man of great destiny" from among them — Connor — to carry out a mission against Katana. At this moment, Katana and his troops attack, crushing the rebellion. Katana orders his men to capture Ramirez and Connor alive, and kill the rest of the rebels. The two captives are put on trial by Zeist’s priests, who sentence them to be exiled and reborn on Earth in pursuit of "The Prize." Winning the Prize gives the victor the choice to either grow old and die on Earth, or to return to Zeist. Katana is unsatisfied with their decision, but the sentence is executed, leading to the events of the original 1986 film.

As such a 4-part question arises:

1. Is everyone on Zeist immortal in general (e.g. lives for at least several centuries)?
2. If "no", how did Katana manage to survive on Zeist long enough to wait from back-when-Ramirez was sent to Earth till 2024?
3. Is anyone/everyone on Zeist an Immortal with capital "I" (e.g. possesses all of the Immortal properties from Highlander mythos, not merely long life? Is there The Game, Quickening, etc... on Zeist?
4. If not, is everyone from Zeist an Immortal when beamed to Earth (ala Superman mythos)?

Please note that the question seeks primarily **in-universe** answers (but not necessarily sourced from the movie itself); and applies only to theatrical version of the movie, not alternate cuts where the events in the quote above happen on Earth in the past instead of on the planet Zeist.

Comment: Can't we all agree Highlander 2 was a hideous mistake and just move on?

Comment: @Wikis - No. It's an array, not a linked list.

Comment: But Zeist is not even a planet, it's [a town](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=zeist&hl=en&ll=52.090476,5.233612&spn=0.532417,1.231842&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=43.713406,78.837891&hnear=Zeist,+Utrecht,+The+Netherlands&t=m&z=10&iwloc=A) right here on Earth.

Comment: @DVK It's only prudent for a list iterator to skip elements that don't parse >_>

Comment: I agree with @Wikis with the condition that "just moving on" means ignoring everything but the original _Highlander_ movie. Problem solved!

Answer (score 4):

In the *Renegade Version* of *Highlander 2*, which has replaced Zeist with ancient Earth, Louise explains the immortality like so: (39 minutes into the film)

> You're mortal there, but you're immortal here.  Until you kill all the guys from there who have come here, and then you're mortal here.  Unless you go back there, or some more guys from there come here in which case you become immortal here again.

"Here" meaning modern Earth. "There" meaning Zeist/ancient Earth.  There's no explanation for how time passes on Zeist/ancient Earth compared to modern Earth, so there's no explanation for how Katana viewed the centuries of time that Connor lived on modern Earth.

Comment: There's a Renegade Version? Any good?

Comment: @JohnC Haha, a 'good' version of *Highlander 2*!?  Good one.  (It is quite terrible.)

Comment: It would have made more sense if it was FUTURE Earth, not past Earth. And the Immortals were just evolved humans who shared a finite energy source that kept them young. That way, they were sending them back into the past, and the shared energy was why they were going around offing each other. At least that would have... ah, never mind.

Answer (score 3):

The original script explained very clearly why Connor and Ramirez were immortal on Earth when they were sentenced.

> **JUDGE:** "I sentence you to exile from Zeist. You will be transported to the planet Earth. Each of you to a different time and place. There to be reborn. Once you have grown to the age you are now, time itself will take on a new meaning for you. One year on Earth is like one day on our planet. So on Earth you will be immortal. Furthermore, your memory of this planet and your lives here will be gone. Until the time of the Gathering.

Comment: Do you have a link to the original script?

Comment: Here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B74uEzzkDbNjZ21XX0h4M0k1YkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

No. Only a select few Zeistians (Zeisters?) possess the gift of immortality. Ramirez and Connor are two of those, as are General Katana and his two winged monkeys.

From the [transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=highlander-ii);

> **Judge:** *As you well know, for many years we have exiled **those rebels and criminals who, like you, possess this unholy immortality.***
>
> *Therefore, I sentence you both to this same exile an exile into the
>   future.*

This immortality would explain why Katana is still alive centuries later.